# Graficar n funciones en php

Tags: php, html, canvas

El programa consiste en graficar una cantidad de funciones en una misma gráfica pero al momento de pasar los datos no entiendo como mandarle los datos de todas las funciones, solo puedo graficar 2 funciones porque en la parte de json_encode le coloco los datos de cada función.

```
<?php
//n Número ingresado por el usuario
$n=2;
//Retorna el resultado de una función 
function RespFuncion($funcion, $x) {...}
//Función de legrende
function legendre($n){...}
//Funciones
for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++){
  $funciones[$j]=legendre($j+1);
}
//Valores de cada función
for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++){
echo $funciones[$j]."<br>";
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    $dataAux[$i]=array("y" => RespFuncion($funciones[$j], $i), "x" => $i);
}
$data[$j]=$dataAux;
}
?>
```

//No es obligatorio utilizar CanvasJS

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
title: {
    text: "Funcion Y(x)"
},
axisY: {
    title: "Eje Y",        
},
    axisX: {
    title: "Eje X",      
},
data: [{
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($data[0], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?> },
    {
    type: "line",
    dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($data[1], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);?> }]
});
chart.render();
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<center>
<div id="chartContainer"   style="height: 200px; width: 50%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Por qué no devolver el `object` de configuración del Chart (JS) desde PHP? Algo así:
Me creo el mío propio a modo de ejemplo (usando como referencia la doc de la librería de cómo es el objeto de configuración).

```
$datapoints = [];
$one = [ //lo que devuelve la funcion 1
    "type" => "line",
    "dataPoints" => [
        "label" => "apple",
        "y" => 10
    ]
];

$two = [ //lo que devuelve la funcion 2
    "type" => "line",
    "dataPoints" => [
        "label" => "apple",
        "y" => 5
    ]
];
$datapoints[] = $one;
$datapoints[] = $two;
 // añadimos al array de data
$final = [
    "title" => [
        "text" => "Funcion Y(x)"
    ],
    "axisY" => [
        "title" => "Eje Y",
    ],
    "axisX" => [
        "title" => "Eje X",
    ]
];
$final["data"] = $datapoints;
echo json_encode($final);
```

devuelve todo el objeto de configuración.

Luego en el JS solo tendrías que hacer

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",json_encode($final))
```

En tu loop sería algo así

```
$final = [
... // los datos de config
]
$dataPoints = [];
for($j=0;$j<$n;$j++){
  for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    $dataPoints[]=["y" => RespFuncion($funciones[$j], $i), "x" => $i];
  }
}
$final["data"] = $dataPoints;
```

Y en el JS, lo mismo que he puesto antes.

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",json_encode($final))
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, cuando mando a compilar me muestra por ejemplo {"title":{"text":"Funcion Y(x)"},"axisY":{"title":"Eje Y"},"axisX":{"title":"Eje X"},"data":[{"type":"line","dataPoints":[{"y":0,"x":0},{"y":1,"x":1},{"y":2,"x":2}]},{"type":"line","dataPoints":[{"y":-0.5,"x":0},{"y":1,"x":1},{"y":5.5,"x":2}]}]}  le modifique algunas cosas para que me retorne de esa manera pero no se muestran en la gráfica. Cuando copio lo que retorna y le pego directamente en el CanvasJS.Chart si se muestran en la gráfica :(

Comment: Con esto se solucionó :D, gracias!!!                                                                                           var datosFunciones = <?php echo json_encode($final); ?>;
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",  datosFunciones);

Comment: Nada!!! Me alegro que dieses con el fallo. La costumbre de usar Laravel y no tener que escribir `<?php echo ... ?>` y por eso te pasé un json_encode sin más jejeje.

Comment: Porsiacaso sabes de alguna propiedad o método para colocar los nombres de las funciones?(ej: F1, F2 algo simple). Al tener muchas funciones no sabría que grafica es de una función.

Comment: No entiendo del todo lo que quieres hacer...

Comment: Colocar un nombre a cada gráfico y que sea visible